# configure .net assemblies exception

Tags: .net, exception, io, system

Would it be possible to alter the exception handling behavior of .NET assembly by configuring it somehow. I have a third-party application & every time I start it, it throws an exception msg ->

---

### Cannot create a file when that file already exists.

This is System.IO.Exception. I want to change the assembly behavior - It should not display exception msg - just continue with assembly execution.

Comment: Why don't you solve the problem instead, by checking if the file exists before you attempt to create it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible, if the application itself does not support it explicitly. The exception probably get's thrown, because the assembly creates a `FileStream` with [`FileMode.CreateNew`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filemode.aspx), resulting in an [`System.IO.IOException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ioexception.aspx).

The only thing you can probably do is writing your own application, that checks if the file that get's created by the 3rd party application exists and if so, delete it. Then your application launches the 3rd party app.